# How do I read the value from the input readonly class using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

How do I read the value from the input readonly class  ?

I am trying to use query selector in chrome dev tools but unfortunately I cannot display the value from this field. I tried putting it at the end

> textContent , .innerText

i but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

use `value` ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDataElement/value)) of the input:

```
document.querySelector('YOUR_IDENTIFIER').value
```

example (see the console):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ppxglq?file=index.js